# Can I use a custom Membership provider for use in an asp 3.5 .net windows authentication application?

Tags: asp.net-membership, windows-authentication

In an Intranet asp.net application, I need to use Windows authentication, however, I must filter user access to the application. I also have to use an already defined database schema with the users info and profile, so I must handle the ValidateUser. How can I use a custom membership provider with windows authentication?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To use the Windows authentication see [WindowsPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.aspx) and [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx). 
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/52kd59t0%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for details about role based security.

To build your own custom authentication using users from a database see [GenericPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericprincipal.aspx) and [GenericIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericidentity%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9dd5fx0%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for some details regarding custom authentication.